# Cannot redirect to a file descriptor stored in a variable

Tags: bash, verbosity

<sup>**Editor's note**: This question has undergone several revisions that altered the nature of the problem, potentially invalidating older comments and answers; its original title was "Cannot redirect Bash output to /dev/null".</sup>

I'm trying to create a small Bash script for which I'd like to implement a silent mode. Basically I'd just like to hide most of the output by default and, in case I run it with `-v`, show all output.

So at the beginning of my script I've put :

```
#!/bin/bash
declare output=''
if [ "$1" = -v ]; then
  output="&1"
else
  output="/dev/null"
fi
```

Then in my scripts I have:

```
{
  # whatever commands...
} > $output 2>&1
```

The silent mode works well. However, if I try the verbose mode, a file called either `&` or `&1` (based on my `output` variable) is being created. Also, the file is empty. This is not the desired outcome: I want the output to stay on the terminal!

Is this due to the order in which I redirect or is it my variable which is wrong? EDIT: The script now works fully, by replacing `"&1"` as output value with `"/dev/tty"`.

Comment: Try http://shellcheck.net/ before posting here. Nominating to close as simple typo.

Comment: Thanks for the link! However, even after fixing the typo, there is an issue: whether the verbose mode is on or off, the output is always the same.

Comment: @Lupuss Redirect stderr as well

Comment: You can redirect stdout and stderr forever with `exec > /dev/null 2>&1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably the error output is getting printed. Note that with `> /dev/null` only stdout is redirected and stderr is not. You can use `2>&1` to redirect stderr to stdout before redirecting stdout. Something like:

```
{
  # whatever commands...
} > $output 2>&1
```

Comment: Now it works fine when I am in "silent" mode but not verbose mode :)

Comment: With the benefit of hindsight (unfortunately, the OP changed the question multiple times):
While this answer shows a generally helpful technique - how to send stderr output to the same target that stdout output is sent (redirected) to -
it doesn't address the OP's final version of the problem, which stems from trying to store a redirection to a file _descriptor_ in a _variable_, which is not supported.
Quibble: `2>&1` doesn't redirect stderr _before_ redirecting stdout; rather, it redirects stderr to the _already-redirected_ stdout, i.e., _after_ stdout has been redirected.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**

- You can't store redirections to *file descriptors* (`&1` in your case) in *variables* - if you do, you'll create a *file* by that name instead (a file literally named `&1` in your case).
- Setting `$output` to `/dev/tty` is ill-advised, because you then *always* output to the terminal, which prevents capturing the verbose output in a file; e.g., `script -v > file` won't work.
- Take  [gniourf_gniourf's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1815797/gniourf-gniourf) advice from the comments, and use `exec` instead: `exec > /dev/null 2>&1` or, using Bash-specific syntax, `exec &>/dev/null` silences the remainder of the script.

---

Redirecting to a file descriptor only works:

- if the redirection target is a *literal*, not a variable reference.
- if there are *no spaces* between the `>` and the target.

```
date > &1 # !! SYNTAX ERROR: syntax error near unexpected token `&'

date >&1  # OK - but works with a *literal* `&1` only
```

If you use a *variable*, that doesn't matter, because the variable content is invariably interpreted as a *filename* - that's why you didn't get a syntax error, but wound up with an output file literally named `&1` instead.

```
output='&1'
date >$output  #  !! Creates a *file* named '&1'.
date > $output #  !! Ditto.
```

To solve your problem, I suggest taking [gniourf_gniourf's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1815797/gniourf-gniourf) advice from the comments: use `exec` instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ $1 == '-v' ]]; then
  : # verbose mode: redirect nothing
else 
  # quiet mode: silence both stdout and stderr
  exec &>/dev/null
fi

echo 'hello'      # will only print with -v specified
echo 'hello' >&2  # ditto
```